# Get simple Salesforce freelancing work

Tags: opportunity, validation, developer-console

I am a web developer with master degree of CS. but I know **nothing** about this system.

There are many opportunities for freelancing work with Salesforce, so I need suggestions **according simple tasks can I learn in short time**.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off topic because SFSE is not a job board.

Answer (score 2):

[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com) is the place for you to start off.

Everyone can learn Salesforce. Whether you are an admin, user, or developer, there is a trail for you.

It has trails (chapters), modules and even projects to get experience!

You can filter by beginner level and start to learn Salesforce in a fun and easy way!